# OSGi container for Android

Tags: android, osgi

I'm working in a project similar to Taintdroid that uses a scientific technique called "dynamic taint analysis" . 
So I have to find the appropriete containers for OSGi to deploy on android.
I find answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560794/what-osgi-container-do-you-recommend 
but it is is not destinated to Smartphones.
So what's the favorites OSGi containers for Smartphones and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Apache Felix, which has support for Android [out of the box](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html). I like it because of its 'clean' OSGi implementation, and its modest footprint makes it a good choice for a smartphone (especially since componentizing your application stops some of the Android tooling's optimizations).

Other than that, assuming that you get other containers to run on your device, it all comes down to personal preference and finding the best fit for your situation.

Comment: thank you for replying , Unfortunately , i found problems in copying felix .dex files on /data , because we must that we have root permission(the phone must be rooted).Have you any explications or sollutions?

Comment: Well, what I do is (a) put all my bundles on a the application classpath, and start the Activators (this saves you the hassle of de-duplicating classes too), and (b) when I need to install additional bundles, stream them in from outside.