# Best choice for OSGI implementation with Android

Tags: android, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I want to develop an android application that supports dynamic loading and unloading of bundles. Therefore, I am considering using an OSGI implementation framework.

What would be my best OSGI implementation choice?

By best, I am talking about Documentation (Availability of resources), Compatibility with Android API, and support for embedding OSGI in Android Application.

While searching, I found two implementations that seem to be good:

1- [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html)

2- [Knopflerfish](http://nilvec.com/embedding-osgi-into-an-android-application-part-1.html)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I read rumours that Knopflerfish worked on Android once. However, it is a question to me if it can work at all. In Dalvik VM one app can have 65535 methods (it might have been changed in the latest versions). If you start using many bundles in one app you reach this number pretty fast. In a year or something I would like to spend some time on this question but I think I will check if I can run an OSGi container on Avian VM (that can be compiled to Android-linux)

Answer (score 3):

Both work on Android. Like Balazs pointed out in a comment, there are quite a few subtle differences between Dalvik and the JVM and some of those do bite you when doing OSGi style dynamic loading of code. From memory, you also have to worry about not being able to load the same class twice (even if they are privately packaged in different bundles). However, since you're probably designing the application from scratch, you can probably work around such issues.

You will also find some information here: [OSGi container for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192452/osgi-container-for-android)

One tricky aspect though is that Android is also a bit of a moving target. The first version of Android did not have the classloader methods exposed that we needed to get Felix running, so we had to do a bit of reverse engineering. It is hard to predict what future versions of Android will bring though. Things might break. Are you going to choose your own version of Android and deploy it to the devices you target, or does the code need to run on existing devices?